# Spring integration process message when all other messages finished processing

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, integration

is there a way that that a component in the spring integration graph will start processing a message (end of day) first when all other messages (other type) finished processing? in this question we have to consider that spring integrations can start multiple threads. An other restriction is that this component will be used in graphs where i have no control. so i can not tell:

- how long "other type" message processing takes
- if some messages run in error
- are just drop by some filter
- multiplied with a publish-subscribe channel
- if there are some TaskExecutor used (introduces new thread and transaction boundary)
- there is no end artifact which i could check if it is there or not

when "end of day" arrives to my component it is possible that "other type" messages are still in processing. even if my component is at the end of the graph it is possible that messages run it error not arrive there. other posibility that a message is mutiplied and i do not know how many times. because of this i do not know how long i should wait with the "end o day" processing.

it is also possible that an other tool/framework would make this problem easier or eliminate it completely.

Comment: You just give us impossible task: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_There,_Don%27t_Know_Where. How can give you some solution if you fully don't have any hooks from those processes to be sure that they are finished? You may have something like "idle flag" to see that no more activity in the app, but since you can't modify that solution, you are doomed. Please, correct me if I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: would be nice to have a solution for this impossible task :-) was tinking about checking the task executor if all threads are free, but there might be several task executors some of which not involved. the next best solution we came up with is counting the messages at the begining of the graph and before our component. if those 2 match (+error channel) then all messages processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> was tinking about checking the task executor if all threads are free, but there might be several task executors some of which not involved.

This sounds like not related to what you say in the question, when you claim that process you use is a black box.

If you really can have access somehow to the process, e.g. via `ChannelInterceptor`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-interceptors, so you can have some global bean like `AtomicBoolean active` to set in the beginning of the flow and reset in the end. So, your "in the end of day" message would poll this flag periodically to be sure when to send it. You just simply can use a `@InboundChannelAdapter` to produce your message or `null` when flag is `false`.